# Need help inputing multiple integers in one line with stringstream in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to make a program that input multiple integers in a single line without knowing the number of that integer itself. So I think I'll use sstream, but get stucked because this is my first time using sstream.

```
string zzz;
int i=0,current;
int main()
{

    stringstream ss;

    getline(cin,zzz);
    while(stringstream(zzz)>> i) 
    {
        cout << i<< endl;
    }

}
```

example if I'm inputing 123 456 it will result in infinite loop of printing 123. How can that be happen?

Comment: If you're planning to use `operator >>` anyway to read the integers, you may do so directly from `std::cin`.

Comment: @Edward: But then you won't be able to differentiate between integers on one line, and integers on the next, which is the point.

Comment: But if I'm using std::cin I got EOF problem, that's why I'm using getline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `stringstream(zzz) >> i` is evaluated in each iteration. That means each time the loop condition is checked, you are creating a new *stream* with the same content as before.

If you move the *stringstream* before the loop, it should work as expected:

```
getline(cin,zzz);
stringstream ss(zzz);
while(ss>> i) 
{
    cout << i<< endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While @nosid's answer does work, the use of `std::getline()` in this context would be ill-advised as this task can more simply be done with the direct use of the extractor:

```c++
while (std::cin >> i)
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```